# Advanced Line Follower robot

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, robotics, python

I know about line follower mainly the grid solving robots i know the basics actually. Actually they have to trace the path of the grid in an arena and then reach back to starting point in a shortest distance. Here my doubt is regarding the line follower in this link I have attached.[Advanced Line Follower Robot for maze solving](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5At_u5rnh2U)

My doubt is what are the procedures to do it? They have mapped the path and used Dijkstra algorithm to solve the path. But how do they transfer the code(i.e) where it has to turn which direction it has to turn. how are they generating the what function should be passed? Please explain i need the procedure alone. am going to try it with python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any language will do, as long as it is supported by your HW platform.
If you want to use python, you need a board that can run python.
That could be an Arduino Yun, for example. Or an Intel Quark. Or an Intel Edison with an Arduino shield.
But these will be expensive.

You could, alternatively, use C/C++ and an Ardino UNO (or micro, nano, mini pro), which is far cheaper.

Googling for something as simple as "Arduino line following kit" gives as first answer [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Line-following-Robot-with-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS), which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Please read my question and see the link I have attached.

Comment: Why do you think I didn't do that? Try instead with a constructive comment, explaining what of my answer is not matching your question.

Comment: Did you see the link? They have just mapped the arena and did it. I want to know the procedures exactly how they did it. I didn't ask whether it will work with python. Arduino works with python-pySerial

Comment: I did watch the link, but you need to ask _them_ exactly how they did it. 
Other than that, pySerial is not sufficient. It will let you run python code to talk to the arduino, but you need something on the Arduino to listen to it and take the corresponding actions. And send to the PC where your python program is running all the information coming from the sensors.

Comment: Oh, wait, are you thinking to continuously poll the sensor over the connection? That might work, but it's kinda lame.

Comment: No sir, I just need to know how they did it? I searched many blogs. Actually what kind of implementation is this?